# Wordpress image description

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I'm new in wordpress. I posted images through 'add media'. What I want is to display its description in a popup window once I clicked the image. But by default, description is not displayed. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check wordpress plugin repository for this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. The simplest way would be to use a lightbox plugin, or to write a simple javascript plugin that uses the image's ALT attribute and displays it on click.

Comment: But the thing is.. It's the image being popped out not the description of the image. Is there a way or plugin to do this? I tried to alter some scripts but it seems its not working.

Comment: Refer to the second part of my answer. A few lines of jQuery will easily get the job done without any plugin polluting your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin to use is [slimbox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slimbox/).